# PHP - Implementing a Primary key SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wamp, primary-key

```
    <?php
    require_once 'Connect.php';


    //Prepare HTML insert statement binding parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO records (`Title`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, `DOB`, `Mem.Expiry`, `Mem.Type`, `EmailAddress`) 
    VALUES (:Title, :Fname, :Lname, :Gender, :DOB, :MemX, :MemType, :Email)");



        $title = $_POST['Title'];
        $fname = $_POST['Fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['Lname'];
        $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
        $dob = $_POST['DOB'];
        $memx = $_POST['MemX'];
        $memtype = $_POST['MemType'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];


    //Attempt row insertion by executing prepared statement
    try
    {
        //Insert a row

        $stmt ->bindParam(':Title', $title);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Fname', $fname);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Lname', $lname);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Gender', $gender);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':DOB', $dob);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':MemX', $memx);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':MemType', $memtype);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':Email', $email);

        $stmt->execute();

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


?>
```

I have a web form that updates a database connected to localhost. I would like to implement a primary key. When I include the ID column and set it to primary key, how can I implement that it auto fills in the code above? I have looked online, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

I cleared the database and inserted a primary key. Now when I fill out the form the first input will be uploaded and the primary key will be 0. After this no other information is being registered?

Comment: You dont. If it is Auto Increment just leave it out of the INSERT query completely. MYSQL looks after creating the next number in that column

Comment: The first AutoIncrement key is normally 1 when you leave MYSQL to do all the work

Comment: Seperate NOTE: `$conn->prepare()` should be inside your `try/catch`, that is just as likely or in fact MORE likely to throw an exception than `bindParam` and `execute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: I cleared the database and inserted a primary key. Now when I fill out the form the first input will be uploaded and the primary key will be 0. After this no other information is being registered?

Comment: Now everytime you insert a new row to the table, mysql should create a new id. (Starting by 1, if no other value set/given). The CREATE Statement would help. (Or the ALTER table if you worked with this).